# Does Kibana support filters with preset values in a dropdown

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-3

I wanted to know if I can create dropdown filter options for my visualizations in Kibana similar to the data filter Kibana has which when set to the last day, updates all visualizations in a dashboard to reflect information only where data is within the specified bounds..

It would be helpful to have a dropdown for example that says 

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Pear
- Cherry

And upon clicking one of these, for example Orange, have the visualizations in my dashboard update to reflect only the data where Fruits=Orange.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly a drop down, closest I am aware of that will get you the clickable filtering is using a data table visual with a 'split rows' by term aggregation in Kibana 4 - if you are using kibana 3 it would be a terms panel.

For Kibana 4 - After selecting split rows under the bucket area within the data table, You would select 'Terms' for aggregation, 'Fruits' for your field and complete rest of options to your liking. Save the Fruits data table and add the visual to your dashboard.

Clicking the value of the fruit in the data table will add a filter to the dashboard. This same concept can be completed using other visuals in Kibana 4 such as the Pie chart (split pie by term aggregation) or vertical bar (split x-axis by term aggregation).